# How to create a series of emails, to attach files in a folder, while limiting the number of files attached to any one email?

Tags: vba, file, email, outlook, attachment

I need to attach files from a selected folder to an Outlook email.

If number of files is 15, for example, then 2 emails should be created. The first email would contain the first 10 files and the second email would contain the remaining 5.
In other words, one email can contain no more than 10 files, if there are more than 10 files in a folder, keep creating new emails and attaching files until all are attached.

The following code creates the correct amount of emails (if there are 12 files it creates 2 emails) but attaches all files to every email (both emails contain 12 files).

```vb
Sub attach()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set fls = f.Files
    
    Z = 10
    
    For d = 0 To fls.Count - 1 Step 10
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        'On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "abc@gmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .subject = "file"
            
            y = 0
            For Each x In fls
                If y < Z Then
                    .Attachments.Add (sFolder & "\" & x.Name)
                    y = y + 1
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            
                Z = Z + 10
            Next
            .Display
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you fix the  `Attachements` typo from the previous question.

Comment: yeah, I fixed it. The issue still remains

Comment: I would suggest putting the file paths into an array and looping over that.  You can easily get the number of files from the number of elements in the array.  Then  create another email after the 10th and attach the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `fls` cannot be iterated by index, put the files into a Collection.  Once you do this, the logic becomes very simple.  The code below highlights how to get the correct number of attachments for each email.  You can modify it to add Outlook-specific calls to actually create the emails:

```
'add the files to a collection so we can iterate by index
Set cFiles = New Collection
   
For Each f In fls
   cFiles.Add sFolder & "\" & f.Name
Next
   
'build our emails
For i = 0 To cFiles.Count - 1
   If i Mod 10 = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "New email"
   End If
   
   Debug.Print "Attachment:  " & cFiles(i + 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `Mod` function which divides two numbers and returns only the remainder, see the following code:

```
Z = 10

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

For d = 0 To fls.Count - 1

  If (d Mod 10) == 0 Then
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
  End If

  'On Error Resume Next
   With OutMail
      .To = "abc@gmail.com"
      .CC = ""
      .subject = "file"
        
      y = 0

        'set reference to the x file there

        If y < Z Then
          .Attachments.Add (sFolder & "\" & x.Name)
           y = y + 1
        Else
          Exit For
        End If
        
       If (d Mod 9) == 0 Then
          .Display
       End If   
        
    End With

Next
```